# dynamic number of piecharts using raphaeljs

Tags: php, javascript, raphael, parameter-passing, pie-chart

I am trying to visualize the results of votes stored in a MySQL DB. I have questions in the DB and answers to those questions, each answer has 5 numerical values. In the list below, Q symbolizes the question text and the numbers are the answers to that question.

```
Q1 - 45,32,12,1,6
Q2 - 23,2,14,0,53
..
..
Q7 - ...
```

If you think about the scenario above, I need to show 7 different piecharts on the screen. However, the number of Questions are not fixed they may either increase or decrease. In that case, the number of the piecharts on the screen may also increase or decrease.

Currently, I am using the code below for the piechart:

```
function displayChart() {

    var r = Raphael("holder");
    pie = r.piechart(100, 100, 70, [<?php echo($startValues) ?>], { legend: ["%%.% - 5 Stars","%%.% - 4 Stars","%%.% - 3 Stars","%%.% - 2 Stars","%%.% - 1 Star"], "colors":["#1a9641","#a6d96a","#d9ef8b","#fdae61","#d7191c"], legendpos: "east"});
    //blue-red colors ["#0571b0","#92c5de","#e7e7e7","#f4a582","#ca0020"]

    pie.each(function(){
        this.sector.scale(0, 0, this.cx, this.cy);
        this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 1000, "bounce");
    });

    pie.hover(function () {
        this.sector.stop();
        this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

        if (this.label) {
            this.label[0].stop();
            this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
            this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
        }
    }, function () {
        this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 300, "bounce");

        if (this.label) {
            this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
            this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 500 });
        }
    });
};

window.onload = function () {

    displayChart();

};
```

and render the output to

```
<div id='holder' style='height:200px;'></div>
```

I can display the Questions (I mean the text that I grab from the DB) on the screen dynamically but can't handle the piechart(s). I would be glad if you may help me with it.

No matter what I tried, I could **not** dynamically align the piecharts and could not make them display different results.

I am also unsure how to pass those values to the function, somehow the standard definitions didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this  is what you're looking for.

I've made an array of your question values

```
var vals = [
[ 1,2,3,4,5],  
[ 3,5,8,9,1],  
[ 10,100,150,20,70]  
];
```

and then just offset the piecharts based on their index in the array.

```
pie = r.piechart(100, (200*loop)+100, 70, vals[loop], { legend: ["%%.% - 5 Stars","%%.% - 4 Stars","%%.% - 3 Stars","%%.% - 2 Stars","%%.% - 1 Star"], "colors":["#1a9641","#a6d96a","#d9ef8b","#fdae61","#d7191c"], legendpos: "east"});
```

It can't be that simple, can it?

Here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/BVWZq/)

Comment: Hello amadan, thank you for your reply. I need to have it dynamic. For example, if I have 5 entries in the DB than 5 charts will be displayed on one page, if I may have 50 than 5 pages with each consisting 10 piecharts, will be displayed. The problem is, I can not dynamically arrange the places of the piecharts when I render them on the view and/or even if I render (not correctly placed on the screen) than I can't have the charts showing the correct values. All are showing the same value.

Comment: Sorry my answer didn't help. You need to put an example up on jsfiddle or jsbin then to clarify the situation. I assume you're sucking the data out of a database into an array of some sort, so you should be able to emulate the situation there. I'd be glad to look at it if you do.